# Sparse matrix solver with preconditioner

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a `scipy.sparse.csc_matrix` sparse matrix `A` of shape `(N, N)` where `N` is about `15000`. `A` has less than `1 %` non-zero elements.

I need to solve for `Ax=b` as time efficient as possible.

Using `scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve` takes about `350 ms` using `scikit-umfpack`.
`scipy.sparse.linalg.gmres` is with `50 ms` significantly faster when using an `ILU` preconditioner. Without preconditioner it takes more than a minute.

However, creating the preconditioner takes about `1.5 s`. Given that, it would be more efficient to just use `scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve`.

I'm creating the preconditioner `M` with

```
from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator, spilu
ilu = spilu(A)
Mx = lambda x: ilu.solve(x)
M = LinearOperator((N, N), Mx)
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this, such that using `scipy.sparse.linalg.gmres` would be more profitable?

Comment: For me, `scipy.sparse.linalg.cg` and `scipy.sparse.linalg.cgs` are faster than `scipy.sparse.linalg.gmres`, with or without a conditioner. Did you try them ?

Comment: Conjugate gradient methods are for symmetric, positive definite matrices, which is not the case for my problem.

Comment: Give `pypardiso.spsolve` a try. It came out on top when I recently compared sparse matrix solvers for a problem with`< 0.5 %` density. (It works with `csc`, but in my case is fastest when using `csr` matrices)

Comment: Have you tried tweaking spsolve? Tuning the option permc_spec and *not* using umfpack can make the computation faster for some problems. You probably won't get it down by a factor 7, but I've been able to reduce time by up to 30% by benchmarking that in the past.